# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un data.frame dentro de una función?

Tags: r, rstudio

Me gustaría obtener el nombre de un data.frame que esta entrando en una función en R, por ejemplo. Tengo el dataframe:

```
mi_df <- data.frame(
  "entero" = 1:4, 
  "factor" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
  "numero" = c(1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6),
  "cadena" = as.character(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
)
```

resultado:

```
##   entero factor numero cadena
## 1      1      a    1.2      a
## 2      2      b    3.4      b
## 3      3      c    4.5      c
## 4      4      d    5.6      d
```

y mi función es:

```
  ejemplo <- function(x){
    y= x %>% group_by(factor)
    
    Nombre <- "_ss.csv"
    write.csv(datos, Nombre)
}
ejemplo(mi_df)
```

En la variable Nombre dentro de la función, quisiera que este el nombre "x_ss.csv", quiero que x tome el nombre del dataframe de tal forma que mi archivo csv se guarde como:

```
mi_df_ss.csv
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente en cualquier otro lenguaje que no sea R (al menos hasta donde conozco) para hacer lo que preguntas, deberías usar un parámetro extra para indicar el nombre del propio objeto, por ejemplo:

```
ejemplo <- function(x, x_name){
  Nombre <- paste0(x_name, "_ss.csv")
  write.csv(x, Nombre)
}

ejemplo(mi_df, "mi_df")
```

---

Algo que es muy poco genérico, pero R tiene algo que se conoce como "Evaluación no estándar" que es un tema muy grande como para explicar en el marco de una respuesta, pero podríamos decir , que básicamente es la capacidad del lenguaje, que nos permite evaluar antes de evaluar.

En tu caso, la idea sería evaluar el parámetro `x` como la expresión original `ejemplo(mi_df)` y no como los datos que representa `mi_df`. Para esto usamos [`substitute()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substitute)  que nos retorna un objeto que se conoce como árbol de evaluación pero sin evaluar todavía, estudiando este objeto podemos obtener el nombre de la variable que estamos pasando a la función:

```
ejemplo <- function(x){
  x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  Nombre <- paste0(x_name, "_ss.csv")
  write.csv(x, Nombre)
}
```

---

Este código, cuando lo invoques como `ejemplo(mi_df)` generará un archivo `mi_df_ss.csv` con los datos de `mi_df`

#### Importante:

Esto tiene una pequeña complicación cuando se anidan funciones, entre función y función los entornos cambian y el valor del objeto que estamos pasando como parámetro va cambiando, por ejemplo:

```
ejemplo <- function(x){deparse(substitute(x))}
ejemplo2 <- function(x){ejemplo(x)}

ejemplo(mi_df)
[1] "mi_df"

ejemplo2(mi_df)
[1] "x"
```

Vemos que la función inicial retorna correctamente el nombre, pero cuando la anidamos en otra, el nombre del parámetro ya no es el inicial, esto por que han cambiado los entornos de evaluación entre función y función. Digamos que si no vas a anidar esta función en otra, el ejemplo que dí alcanzaría, caso contrario hay un truco ([Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309910/how-to-get-name-of-variable-in-r-substitute)) que es usar en la primer función un segundo parámetro opcional que evalúa el nombre del primero y tomarse el trabajo de trasladar el parametro en todas las funciones que vayamos a anidar hasta el lugar dónde efectivamente vayamos a usar el nombre del objeto:

```
ejemplo <- function(x, x_name=deparse(substitute(x))){x_name}
ejemplo2 <- function(x, x_name=deparse(substitute(x))){ejemplo(x, x_name)}

ejemplo(mi_df)
[1] "mi_df"
ejemplo2(mi_df)
[1] "mi_df"
```

Comment: Si funcionó, muchas gracias por la información.